# Was Rickets commented on as an impediment to Slavery in the North?

Tags: slavery, public-health

The body is able to manufacture vitamin D from exposure to UV light. Dark skinned people will receive less sunlight than a light skinned person because much UV is blocked.

I once visited Baltimore, Maryland, and saw an unusual number of young African American men walking with bow legs and canes.

Papers on the internet suggest that Ricket's Disease is more prevalent among African Americans, even with 20th century nutrition.

In the 17th, 18th, and 19th centuries, did anyone comment on Ricket's impacting the quality of their slaves in the North (where there is less sunlight)?

Comment: Being mostly a childhood onset problem, it seems this would be easily countered (assuming that much of the problem could be understood), by importing people from further south only after the person's bones had already hardened.